# ubuntu is not booting it directly goes to windows 8

Tags: 12.04

I have hp laptop 15 r248 tu

I had already installed Windows 8 and recently I decided to install "Ubuntu studio 12.0". I burnt the iso image to a DVD and I deleted the F drive partition out of 4 primary partitions on my drive and divided it into two parts -  one went in logical and other went in `free` memory. Next I put DVD in the drive and rebooted the PC and it gives this error:

```
Prefix is not set
```

Again it goes to the installation screen and I started the installation process - I choose "Something else" and gave it 2 GB for SWAP 39 GB for EXT4. It's successfully installed and the DVD auto ejected but when I boot my PC its not giving any option for Ubuntu - even when I press a key on the keyboard it directly goes to Windows 8.

Comment: Have you tried using one time boot key, often f10 or f12? Or go into UEIF and set ubuntu as first?  But better to use newer versions of Ubuntu. With 12.04 Dell released Sputnik to add all the drivers Dell systems from 2012 needed. Those fixes were all included in 14.04.

Comment: There r two boot option pressing esc durng booting. One is uefi  and other is legacy but lagacy is actve in llegacy  mark symbol is given to hardisk but when uefi is activated it  doesnt boot anythings  in uefi hard isk option is not given

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair, you can use your live installer flash drive:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

you most likely still have secure boot enabled.  depending on the computer's bios, the secure boot sets default hardware and an OS too boot to, so with this still enabled you can't boot anything else.  You need to reopen your Bios menu, and make sure that that is turned off.  Also, make sure to check your boot order so that windows boot manager comes after any ubuntu entries.  if you can't access your boot menu on startup, you can reach it using windows 8, by accessing the settings menu for  refresh/restore, and go from there.

Comment: Secure boot is not enabled but i want to know how to enable this